# How to get the query string on client side JS for socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I will try to be as detailed as possible. I am using Express, Node.js and Mongoose to build a chat application where friends can message each other personally. I have a list of active users(rendering users who are online), and from the list, I want to click the user I want to message in order to send the personal message.

My approach is: when I click the user, the page generates a query string containing the ID of that particular user, so it has the receiver ID and I have the sender ID. So, I can send the message.

But, for some reason, I am unable to catch the query string from client JS or through socket.io How should I listen for query strings on the client side and the server side to catch the receiver ID?
Right now, my code exists like this:
Server side socket.io:

```
let http=require("http");   //for socket.io
let socketio=require("socket.io");

let users={};
let send=[];
io.on("connection", async (socket)=>{
    console.log("new WS connection");
    socket.on("login", async function(user_id){
        socket.handshake.session.user_id = user_id;
        socket.handshake.session.save();
        
    });

    socket.on("logout", function(user_id){
        if(socket.handshake.session.user_id){
            delete socket.handshake.session.user_id;
            socket.handshake.session.save();
        }
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", async ()=>{

    })

    socket.on("chatMsg", async msg => {
        let sender = await User.findById(socket.handshake.session.user_id);
        io.emit("chatMsg", utils.formatMessage(sender.name, msg));
    })

})
```

Client side socket.io:

```
let chatForm=document.querySelector("#chat-form");
let fullMessageBox=document.querySelector(".full-message-box");
// let ul=document.querySelector(".the-ul");
let li=document.querySelectorAll(".active-people-li");
let div2=document.querySelector(".active-people");
let socket=io();
let record=[];

socket.on("chatMsg", message=>{
    outputMessage(message);  //Outputs message to DOM
    fullMessageBox.scrollTop=fullMessageBox.scrollHeight;

});

chatForm.addEventListener("submit", (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault();
    let msgInput=document.querySelector("#msg-input").value;
    socket.emit("chatMsg", msgInput);
    document.querySelector("#msg-input").value="";
    document.querySelector("#msg-input").focus();
})

function outputActiveUsers(msg){  //Outputs list of active users and generates the query string
    console.log("receiver ID", msg.id);
    console.log("receiver socket id", socket.id);
    let li=document.createElement("li");
    li.classList.add("active-people-li");
    li.innerHTML= `<div class="active-sidebar">
                        <div class="div-of-img">
                            <img src="../files/profile.png" alt="" class="active-profile-img">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <a href="?receiverID=${msg.id}"><h4>${msg.name}</h4></a>
                            <h5>Hi. Is this you, bro?</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>`;
    document.querySelector(".the-ul").appendChild(li);
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try sending the query string through a socket event

Comment: It works the first time. But, after that, it doesn't. why? I have added the code. If I am missing any information I need to upload, please let me know, I will edit it. Because the function outputActiveUsers generates the query string, but it gets called when a client connects and disconnects, so that it why it's getting messed up, maybe? So, it's not working

Comment: This doesn't really provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: Is there no way to catch as soon as the query string gets generated?

Comment: [link](https://socket.io/docs/v3/client-api/index.html#io-url-options) I have seen something about this here @FiFi

Comment: I can't find the proper way. If you know what can be done, please update your answer. It would mean a lot. I have been looking for 3 days now

Comment: You may also refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69054801/failing-to-pass-receivers-idfor-private-message-app-from-client-side-js-to-th